# Let $M$ be a closed subspace of $L^2[0,1]$, is there any convenient way to check if $P_Mf \in L^\infty \cap M$?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $M$ be a closed subspace of $L^2[0,1]$, is there any nice sufficient condition for $f \in L^2[0,1]$ to satisfy $P_Mf \in L^\infty[0,1] \cap M$, where $P_M:L^2[0,1] \to M$ is the orthogonal projection onto $M$?

Thank you for any input.

Answer (score 0):

Not a condition on $f$ itself, without mentioning $M$.

For example, choose some $A \subset [0,1]$ such that the restriction of $f$ to $A$ is bounded, and $M$ the subspace of $L^2$ consisting of functions that are $0$ a.e. outside $A$.  Then 
$P_M f = f I_A \in L^\infty \cap M$ (where $I_A$ is the indicator function of $A$).

On the other hand, let $g \in L^2 \backslash L^\infty$ such that $\langle g, f \rangle \ne 0$, and let $M$ be the linear span of $g$.  Then $P_M f = \langle g, f \rangle g/\|g\|^2 \notin L^\infty$. It's easy to show that such functions $g$ exist as long as $f \ne 0$.

Of course, a sufficient condition on $M$ would be $M \subset L^\infty$.